# Two-way synchronizing of a post type among multisite blogs

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, import, export, sync

Is it possible to two way sync a post type between multiple sites on a multisite install? For example if someone makes a change to an entry under post type "inventory" on Site A how can I make that reflect on Site B automatically and vice versa?

I am thinking that there are two main possible way of doing this, neither of which I'm sure can easily be done.

1) A plugin hooks into the edit_post so when a change is made the plugin edits the sister entry in the other blog's database table.

2) Anytime Site B views or edits an "inventory" post type it is reading it from Site A's database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by sync users. Users are global in the network and can be assigned to any blogs.

"both their public website and backend both use their own multisite blog. "

This doesn't make sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: This post should have been about syncing posts, not users. This is what happens when you lose track of your multitasking.  :)

Comment: Ha! Yeah, makes way more sense now. :)

And yes, those woudl be the two ways you could do it. I don't know of a plugin offhand that will do this for you though. there are ones that will cross-post but I don't think they sync edits.